Can I install the binaries of a package within an activated conda environment?
I need to install some binaries, but I would like to do so in an isolated manner using conda. The problem is this package is not managed by conda nor pip, is there any way I could embed the binaries into my current activate conda environment?

In every conda env, there is a /bin directory that gets added to PATH on environment activation and is removed again after the env is deactivated. If you have an executable that you only want in a specific conda env, simply put it there.
Similarily, there are is also a /lib folder in each conda env where you can place libraries that you only need in a specific conda env
